# Bash script mystery, what exactly did I do here?

Tags: bash

I just finished writing my first working bash script (yay) - it feeds data to GeekTools on OS X and display a task list which updates periodically showing a new project category each time.

I wrote the function getProject, called it once in the script as a test, and then wrote a line that actually sends the info.  Here's the weird part - when I took out the function call I made strictly as a test - the script stopped working!  Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?

Also - as this is my first script, I'd be welcome to advice on better ways of coding it if anyone's willing.  Thanks!

update: the line I removed was "getProject" it was added to test the function, when I removed it I got... nothing, no result whatsoever.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getProject
{

PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd $TMPDIR

if [ ! $STRING ]; then
    declare -ag STRING
    declare -g STRLENGTH
    STRING=($(task ssproject | sort -fbdiu | grep -iv project | grep -iv tasks))
    STRLENGTH=$(task stats | awk '/Projects/ {print $2}')
    STRLENGTH=$(($STRLENGTH-1));
fi 

if [ ! -f ./projectcycle.txt ] || [ $(cat ./projectcycle.txt) -gt $STRLENGTH ] || [ $(cat ./projectcycle.txt) -lt 0 ]]; then
    echo 0 > ./projectcycle.txt
fi  

if [ ! $CYCLE ]; then
    declare -g CYCLE
    CYCLE=$(cat ./projectcycle.txt)
fi

if [[ $CYCLE -lt 0 || $CYCLE -gt $STRLENGTH ]]; then
    CYCLE=0
fi

echo ${STRING[ $CYCLE ]}
CYCLE=$((CYCLE+1))
echo $CYCLE > ./projectcycle.txt
}
getProject  # <-------REMOVING BROKE THE SCRIPT

task projectdisplay project:$(getProject) | grep -v task
```

Comment: Could you update your question so that it is clear what you took out and what the new results were?

Comment: Just to confirm, it is the last ilne that drives your whole process, i.e. `task projectdisplay project:$(getProject) | grep -v task` AND you expecting the function to work via the embedded call `... $(getProject)...` ? (That seems right to me) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

> When things don't go according to plan, you need to determine what
>   exactly causes the script to fail.
>
> Bash provides extensive debugging features.
>
> The most common is to start up the subshell with the -x option, which
>   will run the entire script in debug mode.
>
> Traces of each command plus its arguments are printed to standard
>   output after the commands have been expanded but before they are
>   executed.

```
bash -x script1.sh
```

Otherwise: [Google help for bash debugging](http://www.google.it/search?q=how+to+debug+a+bash+script&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)